# 同じ数字を置換するさいに、数字を昇順に割りあてる方法

Tags: vim

例えば、次のようなファイルがあったとします。

```
0, foo
0, bar
0, hoge
0, fuga
```

この最初の数字(この場合なら0)について、代わりに昇順の数字を割りあてたいと思っています。具体的に言うならば、次のようなテキストにしたいと思っています:

```
1, foo
2, bar
3, hoge
4, fuga
```

さすがに手作業でちまちま編集するのは、どうも非効率に感じます。もしいい方法がありましたら、教えてください。

Answer (score 7):

Vim 7.4.765 以降であれば、対象をビジュアルモードで選択して `g<C-a>` をすると連番が生成されます。

Answer (score 3):

一応、他の方法も書いておきますね。

数字==行番号で良い場合:

```
:%s/^\d\+/\=line(".")
```

ビジュアルモードで選択した範囲内の行頭数字を1から振り直す場合:
(<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>v</kbd>後に複数行選択して<kbd>:</kbd>を押せば`:'<,'>`が自動で入力されます)

```
:'<,'>s/^\d\+/\=line(".")-line("'<")+1
```

Answer (score 0):

少し煩雑になってしまいましたが、マクロ版です。

```
<CTRL-A>:%s/^0//
ggqqyw+P<CTRL-A>0q2@q
```

- `<CTRL-A>`

  - 一行目の 0 に Add します
  - 10 飛びにしたい場合は `10<CTRL-A>`
- `:%s/^0//`

  - それ以外の行頭 0 を消します
- `ggqqyw+P<CTRL-A>0q`

  - 文の頭に戻り (`gg`) レジスタ q にレコーディングを開始 (`qq`)
  - 単語をヤンクし (`yw`) 次の行の行頭に移動し (`+`) カーソル位置の左にペースト (`P`)
  - カーソル位置の数字 (ペーストされた前行の数字) に Add (`<C-A>`)
  - 行頭に戻る (`0`)
  - レコーディングを終了 (`q`)
- `2@q`

  - 繰り返す回数を指定し `@q` でレジスタ q 内のマクロを実行します